# How to auto replace text in a webpage automatically with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome

http://xkcd.com/1031/

[image: xkcd]

It says that XKCD used an extension to accomplish this on a webpage by using a extension that seems to deal with "regex".

What extension can replace words on a webpage with a word you specify?

the Perl (as people believe it is) script that is related to this is specified as "s/keyboard/leopard/"

Help?

Comment: I'd love to see one that's just a web portal and the substitutions can be passed in as URL params — think Google Translate. Know of anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

This one works fairly well: [s/keyboard/leopard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oheflacdocadefgdpiimpapbkomhgbbe). It just needs to be adjusted for Google results.

[image: Wikipedia page for Computer keyboard]

Comment: i found this one for firefox. but still haven't found viable solution for chrome.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxreplace/

Comment: This other extension based of XKCD #1288 shows how easily it can be done: https://github.com/Posnet/xkcd-substitutions